# Wont reset in my pong game (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

```js
function ballReset() {
    ballX = canvas.width/2; 
    ballY = canvas.height/2;
}

function moveAll() {
    ballX += ballSpeedX; //this is the speed of the ball
    ballY += ballSpeedY;

    if(ballX < 0) { // left
        ballSpeedX *= -1;
    }
    if(ballX > canvas.width) { // right
        ballSpeedX *= -1;
    }
    if(ballY < 0) { // top
        ballSpeedY *= -1;
    }
    if(ballY > canvas.height) { //bottom
        ballSpeedY *= -1;
    }
```

Any how, I'm new to this and so far every thing else has checked out but this one thing (getting the game to start over when it hits the bottom of the screen). I can show  more of the code for context if needed.

Comment: Are you expecting the given code to reset your game when the ball hits the bottom of the screen?

Comment: The check is already present in your code.  `if (ballY > canvas.height) { ballReset(); }`  However, if this is the traditional Pong game, you ought to also check for the condition where the ball hits the paddle.

Comment: I don't see any function call in there to reset the game when the ball hits the bottom of the screen. Don't you want something like: `if (ballY >= canvas.height) { gameReset(); }` ?